# iOS keyboard obstructing the editing text in textview

Tags: ios, keyboard, textview, uitextview

I am implementing a textView in my viewController. This textView covers the entire screen since I plan to make this view for users to write down their notes. However, there seems to be a problem when user touches the textview and the keyboard pops up.

The thing is that, once touches the textview, the keyboard shows up half of the screen, and the beginning of the editing text gets hidden behind the keyboard. I tried typing something and didn't see the text at all since the editing text is behind the keyboard. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: hmm, how about changing the 'y' of the superview of your textfields/textview..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the delegate methods for    UITextView in you implementation file and also set delegate of yout     UITextView to self

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGRect rect = txtMessage.frame;
    rect.size.height = 91;// you can set y position according to your convinience
    txtMessage.frame = rect;
    NSLog(@"texView frame is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(textView.frame));

    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    return YES;
}


- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

    CGRect rect = txtMessage.frame;
    rect.size.height = 276; // set back orignal positions
    txtMessage.frame = rect;
   NSLog(@"EndTextView frame is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(textView.frame));

}
```

Comment: I thought that there should be a way to fix this issue via Storyboard. But this code works like a charm as well. Anyway, why do we need textFieldShouldEndEditing here?

Comment: This method is called when the text view is asked to resign the first responder status.YES if editing should stop otherwise, NO if the editing session should continue

Comment: I have implemented another done button on the top-right to let textview resign its first responder status by just using [textView resign responder]. How would this button related to UITextViewDelegate? Do we need to explicitly implement this function every time UITextViewDelegate is used?

Comment: Here read [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html) about this

Answer (score 0):

You have to resize the text view when the keyboard pops up. First of all, define a new method that register your controller for keyboard show and hide notifications:

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

Then call `[self registerForKeyBoardNotifications];` from your `viewDidLoad:` method.

After that, you have to implement the callback methods:

Here's `keyboardWasShown:`, where you get the keyboard's height and subtract that amount to your textView's frame height (as you said, your text view fills up the entire screen so the final height is the previous height minus the keyboard height):

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect rect = self.textView.frame;
    rect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
}
```

And here's `keyboardWillBeHidden:`

```
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    CGRect rect = self.textView.frame;
    rect.size.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
}
```